# Attribute android name does not allowed in manifest?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, android-manifest

How to solve the problem android:name attribute does not allowed here.
The solution that was given in another question does not work for me.

This is my manifest file....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="saleskit.orbitsys.com.androidvolleysingletondemo">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        >

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>



    </application>
    <application
        android:name=".AppController">
    </application>



</manifest>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, there is two application tag remove that. And add the name tag to the existing application tag

> In a manifest file, you can use only one application tag

So Please replace your code by this code. For more information [Refer](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="saleskit.orbitsys.com.androidvolleysingletondemo">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"

    android:name=".AppController"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    >

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>



</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Then where do i register for Appcontroller class that extends applicaton class ?
do you understand what I am saying?

Comment: Check the code I added in the top I have added the  android:name as AppController. In the main application, tag add the application name, not the separate one

Comment: Oops I didn't see your answer.

Comment: @KNeerajLal no problem

Answer (score 2):

You can't have multiple application tags. See the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html#filec).

> Only the `<manifest>` and `<application>` elements are required. They each must be present and can occur only **once**.

Add the `name` attribute to the existing application tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="saleskit.orbitsys.com.androidvolleysingletondemo">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:name=".AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```